# Does the Frechet derivative on a separable Hilbert space commute with the projection onto subspaces?

Tags: functional-analysis, frechet-derivative

Let $H$ be a separable Hilbert space with a fixed orthonormal basis $\{ e_n \}$ and $f : H \to H$ be a sufficiently "nice" mapping so that it has the Frechet derivative $Df \in L(H,H)$.

Here, $L(H,H)$ is the space of bounded linear operators on $H$.

Now, given any subset $S \subset \{ e_n \}$, let $\pi_S : H \to \overline{\langle S \rangle }$ be the projection onto the closed subspace spanned by $S$.

Then, I wonder if $ D[\pi_S \circ f]= \pi_S\circ [Df]$ holds. Clearly, both $ D[\pi_S \circ f]$ and $\pi_S \circ [Df]$ belong to $L(H, \overline{\langle S \rangle})$ but I cannot figure out myself further..

Could anyone help me?

Comment: For exery $x\in H$, the Fréchet derivative $Df(x)$ is a linear operator, $Df$ is a  map $H\to L(H,H)$. Anyway, the chain rule says $D[g\circ f](x)=Dg(f(x)) \circ Df(x)$. Moreover, if $g$ is linear and continuous, then $Dg(y)=g$ for every $y$.

Comment: Please use `\langle` and `\rangle`